# How can 0.2 + rand(0.3) be above 1 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to debug one of the samples in the Sonic Pi 2.0 (a Ruby wrapper to SuperCollider on the Raspberry Pi). I've narrowed the problem code down to this simple few lines of Ruby:

```
loop do
  s = 0.2 + rand(0.3)
  e = s + 0.0625
  puts 's = ' + s.to_s + ', e = ' + e.to_s
  sleep 1
end
```

Looking at [the documenation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Random.html) I would expect that each time through the loop s would be set to a value between 0.2 and 0.5. But no, here's one typical result:

```
==> Starting run 143

[Run 143, Time 0.0]
 +- s = 0.6204361822133666, e = 0.6829361822133666

[Run 143, Time 1.0]
 +- s = 0.2832891087607155, e = 0.3457891087607155

[Run 143, Time 2.0]
 +- s = 0.4914545052249532, e = 0.5539545052249533

[Run 143, Time 3.0]
 +- s = 0.8560154313773802, e = 0.9185154313773802

[Run 143, Time 4.0]
 +- s = 1.1902533463314418, e = 1.2527533463314418
```

Any ideas where those high values for `s` come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're passing a value that is less than one as the `max`. Ruby actually does a `abs.to_i` on the argument and if it evaluates to zero, `rand` will return a number between 0 and 1.

Example:

```
> rand(0.3)   # 0.3.abs.to_i evaluates to 0
=> 0.5406754757491508
```

See [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) for details. They even have a comment on this particular issue:

> Negative or floating point values for max are allowed, but may give surprising results.

If you want to get a number between 0 and 0.3, do this:

```
rand * 0.3
```

Or as Victor pointed out, you can use [Random.rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Random.html#method-c-rand) which works as expected:

```
Random.rand(0.3)   # this will always be >= 0 and < 0.3
```

Comment: hanks for this. It is confusing that [the documenation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Random.html) states that `rand(max)` is an alias for `Random::DEFAULT.rand`. I'll need to be careful which `rand(max)` I'm picking up.

Answer (score 1):

The max param you used on rand behave differently than what you expected:

it says on the doc:

> When max.abs is greater than or equal to 1, rand returns a
>   pseudo-random integer greater than or equal to 0 and less than
>   max.to_i.abs.

so rand(0.3) can get you values like 0.9 and thus

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `rand` (Kernel#rand, the one you're using) and `Random#rand` (the one in the documentation you linked).

You should use the Random#rand in your code.